# Are there any physical phenomena of the heat transfer critically depending on diffusion coefficient? 

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, statistical-physics

Hello,

I am considering the following non-linear heat equation

$$
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\nu\: \Delta \right) u(t,x) = F(t,x) \sigma(u(t,x)),\qquad (t,x)\in R_+\times R^d
$$
where $F(t,x)$ is certain external heat source and $\sigma$ is a Lipschitz continuous function. Let's call $\nu$ the diffusion coefficient.  When I calculate certain properties of the above equation, I find that when $d=1$, the results do not depend on the value of $\nu$, however when $d\ge 2$, the value $\nu$ becomes important. In particular, for the properties that I am studying, we need that $\nu > 1/(2\pi)$ !?.. Does anyone have ever had such critical dependence on $\nu$? Or does anyone know any phenomenon (like phase transitions) depending on $\nu$?

Thank you very much for any hints!

Anand

Comment: Could you elaborate on what properties do you have in mind? Because a dilatation of a space variable $u(x,t)=v(x\nu^{-1/2},t)$ reduces the problem to the case $\nu=1$. So the property you are interested in have to be not invariant under linear transforms.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the exact problem you are studying? Furthermore, even in $d=1$ the solution depends on $\nu$ (Example: $F=0$, then we have the fundamental solution that is $\nu$-dependent). Not quite sure what you are looking for

Comment: @Michael Kissner, yes, the fundamental solution is dependent on $\nu$ for all dimensions, but without $F$, the solution doesn't depend on $ \nu$ on a critical manner. It is essentially change of the time scale. :-)

Comment: Perhaps, but then we need more Information on $F$

Comment: @Andrew, my $F(t,x)$ is certain random noise. I am studying the moments of the solution, whose existence depends critically on the value of $\nu$. I forget to say that it is a nonlinear equation. See my edit.:-)

Comment: @Anand Then it would be nice to write the function $\sigma$. Say if it is а power function,  there is a notion of a critical exponent. It depends on dimension. So the value  of the exponent what is subcritical for $n=1$ could be critical for $n=2$.

Comment: @Andrew, thank you very much for the hints. Actually $\sigma$ is Lipschitz continuous which excludes the power function case. Could you  give me some references on what you mentioned critical values and subcritical values? Thanks a lot!


Comment: As far as I understand the first was the work of Fujita http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/advanced/?q=an%3A0163.34002&format=complete. Many others followed. There are numerous works of Pokhozhaev http://www.mathnet.ru/php/person.phtml?option_lang=eng&personid=12566. Perhaps references to some recent results could be found there. 
  
  

Comment: Here is a link of Andrew's first reference http://repository.dl.itc.u-tokyo.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2261/6061/1/jfs130201.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is very much expected from the statistical physics principle "there is no phase transition in one-dimensional systems with short-range interactions at $T>0$."  See [Lower Critical Dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_dimension#Lower_critical_dimension) in Wikipedia.  Since you  have a PDE your interactions are short-range.  Since you have noise, this corresponds to $T>0$, i.e. non-zero temperature.  The principle states that you should not observe a phase transition when you vary $\nu$ in 1 dimension, but you may in 2 or 3 dimensions.

Comment: Thanks Paul Tupper for your hints. It is very helpful. I am still working on this problem. It takes time. :-)
